# Can the derivative of a characteristic function be also a characteristic function?

Tags: probability-theory

Suppose $\phi(t)$ is a characteristic function, and $\phi'(t)$ exists for all $t$. Then can $\phi'(t)$ be also a characteristic function for some random variable?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No.

If $\phi'$ were to be a characteristic function, then one would have that $\phi(0)=\phi'(0)=1$. That $\phi'(0)=1$ means that the real part of $\phi$ has a slope of $1$ at $t=0$ and the complex part of $\phi$ has a slope of $0$ at $t=0$. Then, one can arrange that $|\phi(t)|>1$ for some small positive $t$, which is impossible.

---

Formally, let $R$ and $I$ denote the real and imaginary parts, respectively, of $\phi$. One then has $R(0)=1$ and $I(0)=0$. If $\phi'(0)=1$, then $R'(0)=1$ and $I'(0)=0$. That $R'(0)=1$ implies that for $t>0$ small enough,
\begin{align*}
\left|\frac{R(t)-R(0)}{t-0}-R'(0)\right|=\left|\frac{R(t)-1}{t}-1\right|<&\;\frac{1}{2},
\end{align*}
so that
\begin{align*}
R(t)>&\;1+\frac{t}{2}.\\
\end{align*}
It follows, in turn, that
\begin{align*}
|\phi(t)|=\sqrt{R(t)^2+I(t)^2}\geq\sqrt{R(t)^2}=|R(t)|>1+\frac{t}{2}>1.
\end{align*}

Comment: Thanks for the prompt reply and detailed proof !